# Permitir que novas condições sejam adicionadas sem modificar código

Tags: c#, .net, if, estilo-de-codificação

Eu estou manipulando um `.txt` e eu tenho que trocar valores do tipo `M31` por `T90` por exemplo.

Meu código está assim no momento:

```
 //Change machine tools for Sodick
                        if (_strLinesFinal.Contains("M50"))
                        {
                            _OS = _OS.Replace("M50", "T90");
                        }

                        if (_strLinesFinal.Contains("M60"))
                        {
                            _OS = _OS.Replace("M60", "T91");
                        }

                        if (_strLinesFinal.Contains("S555"))
                        {
                            _OS = _OS.Replace("S555", "C100");
                        }
```

O problema é que eu vou ter que sempre que adicionar um `if` para cada código que eu querer mudar. Eu queria algo mais prático, talvez colocar em um `app.config`, por exemplo. Como eu posso fazer isso sem ter que ficar adicionando sempre uma condição para a troca de códigos?

Comment: Coloca isso tudo no banco de dados e faz um cadastro em uma área administrativa, acho que seria a melhor opção para você não precisar ficar criando novas builds

Comment: Se você adicionar num arquivo como o `app.config` também vai ter que alterar sempre. Isto te serve? Você não usa nenhum banco de dados?

Comment: posso usar banco de dados também.. pode me dar algum exemplo?

Comment: Você já sabe trabalhar com banco de dados?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isso não é um problema, mas tem razão que pode ser complicado dar manutenção.

Algumas pessoas gostam de fazer algo mais "orientado a objeto". Assim teria um método para cada caso, mas eu acho um exagero.

Tem que analisar o caso específico e eu não tenho a informação do todo. Não sei quem pode adicionar algo. Pode deixar o usuário fazer isso? Mesmo que seja um usuário mais privilegiado. Ou precisa passar pela aprovação do programador antes de colocar isso?

Não existirá caso que seja exceção e a ação a ser tomada seja diferente desta que está no exemplo?

Se realmente é bem comum adicionar novos itens e isso é algo que o usuário pode fazer, o correto é fazer um cadastro de códigos de equivalência. Teria uma tabela no banco de dados com o código achado e o equivalente que deve ser substituído. Aí faz uma tela para alguém atualizar isso, talvez só para alguém privilegiado. Abaixo mostro a base de como fazer a ação mostrada na pergunta.

Se o programador tem que ter ciência desse novo código, não vejo problema em fazer isso no código.

Se quiser evitar tanto `if` é possível fazer uma lista ou dicionário com os códigos e fazer um laço. Seria algo assim:

```
foreach (var item in codigos) if (_strLinesFinal.Contains(item.Key)) _OS = _OS.Replace(item.Key, item.Value);
```

Para inicializar o dicionário seria algo assim:

```
var codigos = new Dictionary {
    ["M50"] = "T90",
    ["M60"] = "T91",
    ["S555"] = "C100", };
```

Se for pegar de um banco de dados em vez desses códigos de equivalente estiver no código da aplicação, ele será criado lendo o banco de dados. Até pode usar o próprio banco de dados direto e nem criar o dicionário. Teria que mudar alguma coisa, mas funciona. Depende do caso. Provavelmente eu faria o *cache* no dicionário. Depende da tecnologia de banco de dados que está usando, mas seria algo assim:

```
var codigos = new Dictionary<string, string>();
using var cmd = new SqlCommand("select codigo, equivalencia from codigos", dbConn));
using var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader());
while (reader.Read()) codigos[(string)reader["codigo"]] = (string)reader["equivalencia"];
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/Generalization.cs).

Mas se tiver ações diferentes de só dar um `Replace()` aí o `if` será necessário.

Comment: boa.. vou tentar fazer isso!

Comment: Perfeito... funcionou... fiz algumas modificações... mas removi metade do meu código com os if .. obrigado!